# Grub Rescue Error. I can boot but need to enter commands again and again

Tags: dual-boot, grubrescue

When I installed Ubuntu I had only windows. So I had the GRUB MENU showing all the options. Now recently I thought of downloading POP_OS! but after downloading I found that I cannot get the Grub Menu. It just loaded POP_OS/1 directly. After pressing `SHIFT` key I got the MENU but there were options for POP_OS! only. I had Ubuntu live disk so I loaded from the usb and deleted the partition of the POP_OS! Now everytime I turn on my computer it says Grub Rescue.

Hopefully for me `(hd0,msdos7)` was an ext2 so I set the boot and prefix and everything was like normal. I could boot into Windows or Ubuntu. But I realised that I had to enter the commands again and again. So I entered the commands and went in to the Ubuntu recovery. Then I chose option `Update GRUB loader`. I did it but still nothing. I have to enter that command again and again.

Is there a way get rid of this **WITHOUT DELETING UBUNTU?**

Comment: The `grub` rescue appears because it has a pointer to an invalid location (it was likely last changed by your installation of Pop OS which took ownership of it; ideally you should have had Ubuntu take ownership of boot (`grub-install`) before removing the Pop partition which would have avoided this). You can `chainload` to Ubuntu from grub & do it now without re-install; you've not said if uEFI or *legacy/MBR* boots your system

Comment: Note: I've made assumptions (*and other than knowing Pop OS boots differently to Ubuntu for some releases, I'm no expert in what Pop has done for your unstated release*), the duplicate link is what I'd believe will help.  uEFI & MBR can differ & you've not said which you use.

Comment: Legacy/MBR booting